# $match _id is not working in Mongoose aggregate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As my title, $match _id is not working in Mongoose aggregate function.
Could somebody please help me?
Is this related to mongoose version?
I use 4.9.2.
I need to use aggregate because I will group by the result after processing the $match.
I already saw posts before, but manually casting didn't work for me!

Here is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var moment = require("moment");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var AvgDailyCharging = new Schema({
    _id : {
        date: Date,
        storeID: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'store'
        }
    },
    chargers: [{ 
        transmitterID: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'device'
        }, 
        minutes: Number
    }],
});

mongoose.model('AvgDailyCharging', AvgDailyCharging);
```

And here is the query:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Model = require('../db/model');
var Query = require('../db/query');

var RESULT_LIMIT = 2000;  // Limit the return data size

exports.getAvgDailyCharging = function(req, res) {
    var id = new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId("58b43fdf0fd53910121ca6f4");
    var query = new Query("AvgDailyCharging");
    query.aggregate([
        { 
            $match: { 
                "_id.storeID": id, //HELP!!!!!
                "_id.date": { //match only by this works fine.
                    $gte: new Date(req.params.startTime),
                    $lt: new Date(req.params.endTime)
                }
            }
        }
    ]).exec(function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({result:'ERROR', message: error});
        } else {
            res.send(data);
        }   
    });
}
```

Please help me!!!! I was stuck for several hours! Q_Q

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? I have a feeling you are being "fancier" than you need to be.

Comment: I only listed the match part. My work is complicated, so I know the aggregate function is needed. By the way, I solved the problem! Match on _id works without type casting in newest version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was testing in mongoose version 4.4.4, both type casting and string didn't work. However, after I update it to the version 4.9.2, type casting is no needed, and directly using a string in $match _id works!

**Update:2017-03-31**

I think another problem in my scenario is my schema definition. Since this collection, say A, is created from another one, say B, using `$group: { _id: { storeID: "$storeID" } }` where the storeID field in collection B is of type `ObjectId`, then in collection A I find out that `_id.store` is actually a `String` not an `ObjectId`, so the best way is to change the schema I mentioned in the question to:

```
var AvgDailyCharging = new Schema({
    _id : {
        date: Date,
        storeID: String
    },
    chargers: [{ 
        transmitterID: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'device'
        }, 
        minutes: Number
    }],
});
```